# encoding slovak letters like: á š Č é

Tags: python, encoding, diacritics

Got a word "Zápas" from one webpage which i srcaped. The problem is that the closest version in my data looks like: Z\xe1pas after windows-1250 encoding.
Without that str(a) there were some ANSI errors. 
Thank you for your help.

my try:

```
def encode(text):
    return text.encode('windows-1250')...
...
for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
    cell=encode(cell.get_text().strip())
    a.append(cell)
foo.write(str(a)+"\n")
```

Comment: Why are you encoding manually instead of having `foo` handle it?

Comment: For anything involving unicode it's very important to specify Python 2 or Python 3 in question and (preferably) tag.

Answer (score 2):

Likely the `a` string is actually a unicode string. To write it to a byte stream you should encode it into a byte string in a specified encoding, `windows-1250` in your case, `utf-8` in my. Just use `a.encode(&lt;encoding&gt;) before sending result to the`foo.write()`:

```
foo.write(a.encode("utf-8"))
```

Also I would process the whole data in `unicode` converting to a byte string immediately before sending the data "outside" (to a file, to a remote destination, etc)